# New line character issue when appending new line to a text file using vba macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros, append

So, I have this piece of code which do exactly what I want: append a new line into a text file using the contents of the cell A1. But when I look at the file, The lines have that "new line" character. How can I avoid my code to write that character?

That's my code.

```
Sub append_data()
    Dim srtfile_path As String
    strfile_path = "C:\Users\me\textfile.txt"
    output = StrConv(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), vbUnicode)
    linebreak = StrConv(vbNewLine, vbUnicode)
    Open strfile_path For Append As #1
    Print #1, output + linebreak
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to remove `+ linebreak`?

Comment: I tried it, don't work, the new line character still in every line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to not only delete the linebreak that you are explicitly writing, but also the linebreak that separates one line from the next in a text file, you need to place a semi-colon (`;`) at the end of the `Print` statement:

```
Sub append_data()
    Dim srtfile_path As String
    strfile_path = "C:\Users\me\textfile.txt"
    output = StrConv(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), vbUnicode)
    Open strfile_path For Append As #1
    Print #1, output;
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, man, that was so simple and worked. I would never figure out the difference of using ";" by myself.